# How to validate dynamic ion-input in ion-list in IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-form-validation

I have a `ion-list`, where I have two `ion-items` in it. In `ion-items` I have `ion-input` which will be dynamically added
on click of add button. I want to validate each `ion-input` , 
below is my code.

```
 <button (click)="add()"></button>
 <form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <ion-list *ngFor="let data of data;">
 <ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Name" type="text"
            formControlName="name">
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngFor="let validation of validation_msg">
    <div *ngIf="myForm.get(name).hasError(validation.type) && 
    (myForm.get(name).dirty || myForm.get(name).touched)">
        {{ validation.message }}
    </div>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Phone" type="tel"
            formControlName="phone">
    </ion-item>
        <div *ngFor="let validation of validation_msg">
    <div *ngIf="myForm.get(phone).hasError(validation.type) && 
    (myForm.get(phone).dirty || myForm.get(phone).touched)">
        {{ validation.message }}
    </div>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 </ion-list>
 </form>
```

Below is my valiation code

```
  data: any;
     constructor(){
       //here I am getting data from api
     }
     this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      phone: new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.required])),
    });
     validation_msg = {
    'name': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'name is required.' },
    ],
    'phone': [
      { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Please enter 10 digit' },
      { type: 'required', message: 'Phone no is required.' },
    ],

  };
  add(){
    // Here I am pushing one more value to data
  }
```

So the normal form validation is working. But when I am clicking on add button , two more fields will come and because of same 
  `formControlName` it is clearing value from first name and phone field. And error msg is displaying for all 4 field.

Can anyone please help me how I can validate this.

Comment: looks like you just need to set `formControlName` based on either the index of list or some id of the data item

Comment: Yes exactly @SurajRao

Comment: @ananya - Please refer this : http://keepnote.cc/code/dynamic-form-generate-from-json-angular-2-reactive-form